# How to make transformable file like Web.config in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web.config-transform

I want to create a file that contains some data.

The file needs to be transformable per configuration/environment (as the Web.config is for Web.Prod.config & Web.Stage.config) and it will be within the deployment packages.
I suppose to use XML file format and I am not sure, if so but I have no clear idea how to implement it.

I appreciate your hints and suggestions to implement above.

Comment: Look at SlowCheetah: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Answer (score 1):

asp.net uses xdt transformation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx )

You can use some external tool like CTT ( http://ctt.codeplex.com/documentation ) and transform whatever file you want during your build process using the same xdt transform syntax.